# Самопроизвольное изменение цвета графика в цикле (matplotlib)

Tags: python, matplotlib

При построении графика в цикле - столбцы меняют цвет при каждом вызове.
Кто-нибудь может сказать в чем причина?
То есть   хочется понять странное поведение matplotlib.

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from matplotlib import mlab
fig = plt.figure()

ax4 = fig.add_subplot(111)
ax4.set_xlim(-10,80)
ax4.set_ylim(0,30)

def view(ylist):

    xmin = 0
    xmax = 70.0
# Шаг между точками
    dx = 10
    xlist = mlab.frange (xmin, xmax, dx)

    ax4.bar(xlist, ylist, dx)
    plt.pause(0.5)
    plt.draw()

ylist = [0 for p in range(8)]
for i in range(10):
    view(ylist)
    ylist[0] +=1
    ylist[3] +=2

plt.close()
```

Comment: Все просто, matplotlib считает что вы выводите новые графики поверх старых, и соответственно задает им новый цвет. Добавьте в цикл перед вызовом функции view вызова метода `plt.cla()`.

Comment: @Avernial - благодарю! Это ответ )